# Conditional update of NumericVectors in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

In `R`, I would use this to update values in a vector matching a conditional criteria:

```
a <- rep(seq(1:20),5)
a[a==5] <- 100
```

How would I go about doing this using `Rcpp` if i had a NumericVector of `a`?

I am new to `Rcpp` and the only way I can think of at the moment is to loop over each value in `a`. I am using this:

```
cppFunction('NumericVector test(NumericVector a){
            int b = a.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            if (a[i] == 5) {
            a[i] = 100;
            }
      }
      return(a);

}')
```

Is there a way of doing this without the loop or with fewer lines of code?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did it fail? Don't expect to get answers like that....

Comment: It is also not exactly polite to fire off questions here every three hours while giving *zero* follow-up to existing questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For standard algorithms like this one, you may find it already implemented in the standard library:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector replace(NumericVector x) {
  std::replace(x.begin(), x.end(), 5, 100);
  return x;
}


/*** R
a <- rep(seq(1:20),5)
replace(a)
a
*/
```

Beware that if input `a` is already of type `double`, it will get modified.

Comment: thanks very much for your suggestion. It works for me. Appreciate the help.